# SMOF cannot retrieve variable values

Tags: php

I am sure that there is a relatively simple answer to this question. Unfortunately my php skills are rather limited and I can't figure it out.

I am using the Slightly Modified Options Framework to add a custom options panel to a Wordpress theme I am developing. The documentation is so sparse as to be almost non-existent, and most of what is published is out of date and incorrect. I am getting no response to my forum post on this issue and I have searched Google for an answer with no result.

At this point I have SMOF installed in my theme, I've customized the options panel and input values which are stored in the database. The documentation says that in order to retrieve the option values for use in the theme you must put `<?php global $smof_data; ?>` in the `<head>` of your document. I have done this.

Now I am trying to use the options variables in my theme. The code I am using looks like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $smof_data['bizname']; ?></h1>
```

No value is returned, page source simply displays `<h1></h1>`

I get the feeling that this is a simplistic php thing that I am supposed to "just know". Unfortunately I do not know it.

If I can figure out how to get this thing running I will write some beginner friendly documentation for this project. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Adding a `global` statement in the head of the document does not make any sense, you use the `global` keyword in functions to access global variables (not really good practice though...). Is `$smof_data` completely empty (try a `var_dump($smof_data)` in the neigbourhood of your `<h1>`)?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sy4mil/Options-Framework/wiki) is the link to the best/most up to date documentation provided. Do you see something that I don't? var_dump returns NULL. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you put `<?php global $smof_data; ?>` in the head of the document or in `header.php`?

Comment: Both. The `<head>` section of the document resides within header.php

Comment: I think you'd have to contact the developer as this is very specific to their plugin / code. Someone here could know it of course...

Comment: I tried :-( He told me to go to the forum, and no-one is answering my question in the forum. Thanks for your time. I appreciate you taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The global varaiable does not pass the value through include or require in header.php. So You can Use This code

```
<?php global $data;
```

$data = of_get_options();
?>